# How does the loader initialize the GOT in ELF/ELF64 executables?

Tags: assembly, x86, executable, x86-64, decompiling

Just like the title says - how does the loader initialize the GOT in ELF/ELF64 executables? I am trying to statically determine what the first entry in the GOT will be, as its initial value is 0.

Comment: Your last 3 or 4 question are about the things that can be found in manuals/specifications. I think that pasting lmgtfy links again isn't original.

Comment: Instead of asking piecemeal questions about linking, loading, etc. you're probably at a point where you need to read technical documentation and/or code for [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), the [x86-64 ELF specification](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/x86-64-abi-0.99.pdf), and [shared library](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) linking and relocation details.